# Trying to move from one actionscript page to another using a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The page it is on is CarSelect.as, the aButton should take it to a page called AClass.as however it doesnt load it.

```
public static var aButton:MovieClip = new AButton();


        addChild (aButton);
        aButton.x = 65;
        aButton.y = 154;
        aButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, openAClass);

        function openAClass(e:MouseEvent):void
        {

            Mercedes.AClass.visible = true;
        }


    //pulling in car actionscript pages
    public var aClass:MovieClip = new AClass();
    public var bClass:MovieClip = new BClass();
    public var cClass:MovieClip = new CClass();
```

Comment: This is not enough information to solve your issue.   What is `Mercedes`?  a custom class? an object instance?  Classes need to be instantiated, so you can't just do `AClass.visible`.   If `ACass` is a display object, you can do `var aClass:AClass = new AClass(); addChild(aClass);` but you need to first instantiate a new instance of that class.  You also can't have var names that are the same as Class names.   So if `Mercedes.AClass` is actually a variable, then rename it so it's not ambiguous with the class `ACass`

Comment: I have a file called mLearning.fla which uses the class file Mercedes.as.

I then have a page called carSelect.as and AClass.as

There is a button that goes from carSelect.as to AClass which is called aButton.

Comment: Then show the part of `Mercedes.as` that initializes it's `ACass` property.

Comment: Ok, you have a typo then.   `Mercedes.AClass.visible = true` should have a lower case 'a':  `Mercedes.aClass.visible = true;`

Comment: Still doesn't like it for some reason
ERROR: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property aClass through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77761/discussion-between-user1888478-and-ldms).

Comment: That's because you haven't instantiated `Mercedes`.    `var car:Mercedes = new Mercedes()`  - `car.aClass.visible = true;`  only things defined as `static` can be accessed from the class reference itself.

Comment: the Mercedes.as page is just the 'homepage' of the app, and the carSelect.as page is the follow on from the homepage and then AClass.as is the next page along from carSelect.as which is accessed from the aButton movieclip.

How do I make the aButton take me to the AClass page?